# How to theme the $content variable's contents?

Tags: theming, 6

I am trying to theme the teasers of a particular content type.

I have gotten to the point where I created a file of name `node-content_type-teaser.php`, where `content_type` is the relevant name.

The trouble is, I am unable to style the actual $content. It outputs the teaser of the text in a `<p>` tag, and an image thumbnail (I get it from a CCK field). I just need to change the order, and output the image first, so I can float it.

To summarize, how do I control the order in which $content is output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is change the order, you do that in the edit content/manage fields form where you can drag and drop the fields in whatever order you want them to be output.

If that's not exactly what you want, you can also change how they are displayed in the "display fields" form.

If all of the above doesn't do exactly what you want, you can print out each field however you want inside the template itself, eg, instead of printing $output, you can print out each field you want when and how.

So, if for example, you have a text field called `field_description,` you can output it by putting a  `print $node->field_description[0]['safe'];` in there since the entire $node is available inside the template to play with.

To see all there is to work with in your specific case, a quick `drupal_set_message('<pre> . print_r($node,true) . '</pre>');` in your template will show you lots of information.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy answer! I had temporarily created a regex that flips the order of output in the teasers, but I was longing to see a more proper manner of doing this. I really should read the docs more carefully :) Thanks again.